# Passing data between activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I wish to pass the value of score from one activity to another. I addExtras to the intent and getExtras in the new activity but it doesn't seem to get the value.

Activity 1;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, EndGame.class);
        intent.putExtra("put_score", score);
        startActivity(intent);
        Game.this.finish();
```

Activity 2;

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        score = extras.getString("put_score");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.endgame);

    scoreResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreNum);

    scoreResult.setText(score);
```

Comment: what value to you see at the `scoreResult`?

Comment: The value of score in activity 1 is 19, the value of score in activity 2 is null. It doesn't seem to either put or get the score value.

Comment: Depending on your manifest settings you might have to capture the intent in onNewIntent(), try overriding that method and see if it receives the expected result.

Comment: What type is `score`? If it is not a `String`, when you call `extras.getString()` it will be null. Use `extras.getInt()` if it is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, Little brain fart there ha, Why I was getting a String is beyond me. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

You problem is coming from the following piece of code in [Bundle.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Bundle.java?av=f#1117):

```
try {
    return (String) o;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    typeWarning(key, o, "String", e);
    return null;
}
```

Here `o` is the object you put to the bundle (bundle actually has a core storage of type `Map<String, Object>`, so, due to autoboxing, when you put `int` to the bundle, it will become `Integer`). But, unfortunately, `Integer` cannot be casted to `String` explicitly, so you get `null` instead. In other words: if you put `int`, then use `getInt` to retrieve the value.

Comment: but ... he did not add a bundle at all! he used putExtra (String,Int) not putExtras(Bundle)!!

Comment: @Yazan it's just shorthand method. All extra data is stored in bundle

Comment: @nikis, did not know that before! dirty secrets of android :)

Answer (score 1):

you placed data in intent using `putExtra` not `putExtras`
so read them the same way

use 
    getXXExtra()
XX is the dataType your data is,

based on the example, if score is Integer, then use:

```
getIntExtra("put_score", 0);//0 zero is default in case data was not found
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html